# Где в OpenCart найти скрипт ответсвенный за добавление товаров в бд из корзины

Tags: php, opencart

У меня перед глазами исходники CMS OpenCart (ocStore-2.1.0.2.1)

И я никак не могу отследить что происходит после оформления заказа

А именно интересует скрипт добавления моего заказа в бд

Если кто знает, подскажите

Comment: Как вы пытались это отследить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите `/catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php` оформление заказа там происходит. А сама запись заказа в БД в модели `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php`